# String conversion to byte array in UTF-8 is becoming larger in size erratically?

Tags: android, string, byte

In my Android application, I'm using file output stream to write data to an internal storage file. The process normally works as expected, however the size of data stored will occasionally become significantly larger than what it should be.

I managed to isolate the problem to a specific section in my code, where I tried debugging by printing the lengths of the String and its byte array counterpart. They appear to be different, despite using UTF-8.

```
String dataToWrite = MainActivity.uniqueID + DELIM + MainActivity.rawCalendarData + DELIM + reminderString.toString();

/*
Up to this point, the length of raw calendar data is still correct. For some reason, dataToWrite almost doubles in length (not exact double)?
*/

fileOutputStream.write(dataToWrite.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
fileOutputStream.close();
Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "Data successfully saved! Length: " + dataToWrite.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length + " bytes (character length: " + dataToWrite.length() + ")");
```

Debugging console:

```
I/App: Saving data...
I/App: Data successfully saved! Length: 1107899 bytes (character length: 583611)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting the number of bytes to be equal to the length of the string? They wouldn't be equal, because UTF-8 uses 1 to 4 bytes to represent a character.